# Improving VS2017 publish AspNetCore performance

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have asp netcore2.0 MVC project and when I publish the project to a folder it takes a long time (fifteen minutes or more). Just to get some data points I benchmarked publishing VS2017 built-in asp netcore2.0 and .net framework webapps templates and here is what I get:

- VS2017 asp netcore 2.0 Empty template: approximately three minutes (00:03:06).
- VS2017 asp netcore 2.0 WebApi template: approximately four minutes (00:04:08).
- VS2017 .net Framework Empty template: approximately 9 seconds (00:00:09).
- VS2017 .net Framework WebMvc template: approximately 15 seconds (00:00:15).

publishing .net framework apps are blazing (as in previous experience) but the netcore app takes a long time.

I think it's because the netcore web packaging does more work and in the end seems to be quite compact (I see precompiled views and controllers) and higher performance than .net. But the publishing time for my app is unbearable.

My question is how can I make the asp netcore 2.0 publish to folder faster?

Comment: What version of VS 2017 are you using?  Have you kept up with the updates?  The latest is 15.3.2.

Comment: It's 15.3.3. It seems to want to copy every assembly... I can publish just the wwwroot node and it take only a few seconds. OK if I didn't touch any cshtml or controllers.

Comment: Does it also occur from the command line?  Can you try opening a developer prompt to your project's directory and type "dotnet publish /clp:PerformanceSummary" and post the output?  That should be able to track down where the time is being spent.

Comment: @EricErhardt the output it too long to paste into comment so it's on my OneDrive. https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjvJkdn_aPt8g_55bDVfGt7CuvAHJg

Comment: When I ran the dotnet publish command from the command line, it took maybe fifteen seconds and put everything in bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish. I copied everything to the deploy folder for IIS and it works fine.

Comment: More info. I have VS2017 on my laptop and created an asp netcore 1.1 empty template app took just a few seconds to publish. I will try upgrading to 2.0.

Comment: this is the output pane when I use the VS2017 publish feature. https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjvJkdn_aPt8g_56Yen4UNGSi32Ohw

Comment: update: I pulled the project in question to another computer with VS2017 and it published in less than 30 seconds. There must be some setting on my problematic machine that's causing the crazy slow publish. @EricErhardt any insights or hints will be greatly appreaciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, nothing stands out to me.  Since it is specific to a machine, it may be something like an anti-virus check that is making it slow?  Can you try temporarily disabling any anti-virus, like Microsoft Defender, and publishing while it is disabled?  If it isn't something like that, I wouldn't know what the problem is.

Comment: @EricErhardt thanks for your help. In the end, a reinstall of VS2017 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the situation feels like the episode in IT Crowd where Moss play the tape to a caller "have you tried rebooting"... Reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 and that fixed the problem.